# Ошибкa в статическом массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_DATA 11

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a[MAX_DATA] = {0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1.3, 1.7, 1.9, 2.3, 2.7, 2.9, 3.3, 3.7};

    double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, temp, s3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        temp = sin(fabs(1 - log(a[i])));
        sum1 += temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp = sin(18 * a[i] * a[i] * a[i]) * sin(18 * a[i] * a[i] * a[i]);
        sum2 += temp;
    }

    if (sum2 == 0) {
        printf("na nol delit nelzya");
    } else {
        s3 = sum1 / sum2;
    }

    printf("S3= %f, S3");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы спутали в тегах C# и C++

Comment: А что по-вашему вот это `printf("S3= %f, S3");` должно выдавать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) принимает первым параметром строку, а затем несколько значений, которые будут подставлены в эту строку. В вашем коде в `printf` передаётся только строка, а значение для модификатора `%f` не передаётся. Так произошло из-за опечатки, чтобы её исправить надо заменить

```
printf("S3= %f, S3");
```

на

```
printf("S3= %f", S3);
```

[Будет выдавать:](https://ideone.com/7e5nJb)

> S3= 0.846996

Comment: А почему именно "значение типа `float`"? Откуда вообще возникло упоминание `float`?

Comment: @AnT для printf в принципе не имеет значения, передаем мы для "%f" значение типа double или float.

Comment: @Croessmah: Это верно, но это тем не менее не объясняет, к чему упомянут `float` в данном ответе.

Comment: @AnT, да, спасибо, убрал